# String codification error when importing sourced script

Tags: r, string, string-formatting

I wrote an R script "test.R" with one line of code:

```
nao <- function () {"não"}
```

Then in another script "call_test.R" we have:

```
source("test.R")
nao()    #Calls nao() in "test.R"

nao2 <- function () {"não"}  #Same function as above
nao2()
```

which results in

```
> nao()
[1] "nÃ£o"

> nao2()
[1] "não"
```

Why do I get different results? (The desired result is `"não"`) How do I get it in the right way from sourced script? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the encoding:

```
source("test.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
```